# Flask-Pymongo send_file not returning the file

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, pymongo

I am trying to upload PDF file or image file from React app into Flask Pymongo. I uploaded the file and then tried to view the file in React app. I am using Flask=1.1.2, Flask-PyMongo=2.3.0, React=^17.0.1.

### React frontend code to try to get the file

```
const [fileURL, setFileURL] = useState(null);
     const result = await axios.get(`${API}/file/${filename}`, {
        responseType: 'blob'
      });
      setFileURL(URL.createObjectURL(result.data));
 <img src={fileURL} alt={match.params.filename} className="view-file"/>
```

### Flask backend code to upload and send file code

```
if 'file' in request.files:
        _file = request.files['file']
        _filename = _file.filename
        _file_mimetype = _file.content_type
        mongo.save_file(_file.filename, request.files['file'])
   
@ app.route('/file/<filename>')
@ cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def file(filename):
    print(filename)
    return mongo.send_file(filename)
```

mongo.send_file() doesn't return anything. I can't view or download the image or pdf file in frontend. Please help me to give some suggestions.